# SQL Functions in defaults- Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table created as

```
create table test
(test_default number(4));
```

Now, I have to add default value 8888 to the column if the length of inserted value is greater than 4.

I have tried

```
alter table test modify test_default DEFAULT 8888 when length(test_default)>4  ;
```

but this does not work. I'm not sure if this can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, with the column size set at 4 you will get an `ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allows for this column` error when attempting to enter a number with a length greater than 4 digits.  Provided you allow a larger value to be entered, a trigger is really what you want (first change the column to a NUMBER(5)):

```
create or replace trigger test_BIU
before insert or update
on test
for each row
begin
  if length(:new.test_default) > 4 then
    :new.test_default := 8888;
  end if;
end test_BIU;
```

Now insert some data:

```
SQL> insert into test values(12345);

1 row created.

SQL> select *
  2  from test;

TEST_DEFAULT
------------
        8888

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use alter modify

```
 alter table test   modify( test_default number(4) default 888 );
```